# How to mutate state using variable in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to `Reactjs` and got stuck while experimenting in my code.I am using `math.random` to find values between `0-9` and concatenating with `valvar` to get multiple variables.I want to find the state of corresponding variable.

Here is my code.

```
 getInitialState: function(){
   return{valvar2:"",valvar3:"",valvar4:"",valvar5:"",valvar6:"",valvar7:"",valvar8:"",valvar9:""}
  },
 handleClick: function(){
  var createVar="";
  createVar ="valvar"+Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
  if(this.state.createVar==""){
     this.setState({createVar:"HELLO"})
  }
```

But this code is not working, I am not sure why.This is just an example not my original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have `createVar` defined in your state, it's just local variable in `handleClick`. So this condition: `this.state.createVar==""` is never met because  it's `undefined`. You have to define `createVar` in your initial state.

If you want to use produced value as state object property name use this:

```
 handleClick: function(){
    var createVar="";
    createVar ="valvar"+Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
    if(this.state[createVar] == ""){
        let newState = {};
        newState[createVar] = "HELLO"
        this.setState(newState)
    }
}
```

or if you use ES2015:

```
this.setState({
   [createVar]: "HELLO"
})
```

Comment: Yes that I know,for example if math.random produces "1" local variable craeteVar will be "valvar1" that is defined in initial state

Comment: Try this `this.state[createVar] ==""`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [babel](https://babeljs.io/) and don't want to mutate your state directly (about mutating state, [see my previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060641/react-changing-the-state-without-using-setstate-must-avoid-it/42061622#42061622)), the easiest way is to use the [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) - wrap the property name in brackets like `[variable]`:

```
const n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)
this.setState({
  ['valvar' + n]: 'hello'
})
```

You can see the example here: http://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/YNjJBb?editors=0011

Answer (score 1):

Directly changing state is [bad](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly).

What you can do in this case is create a object and call `setState` with it.

```
var modifyState = {};
modifyState[createVar] = "HELLO";

this.setState(modifyState);
```

Or even better and cleaner with [ES6 enhanced object literal](http://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#ecmascript-2015-features-enhanced-object-literals)

```
this.setState({
  [createVar]: 'HELLO'
});
```