# setting State without using setState in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I found a tutorial online regarding on React.js but I saw the way the tutor did where he change the state without setState() function. I am here asking whether it is a good practice.

The constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      uid: uuid.v1(),
      name: '',
      answers: {
          answer1: '',
          answer2: '',
          answer3: ''
      },
      isSubmitted: false
    };
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.answerSelected = this.answerSelected.bind(this);
    this.questionSubmitted = this.questionSubmitted.bind(this);
}
```

The way he update the state is:-

```
answerSelected(event) {
    let answers = this.state.answers;
    if (event.target.name === 'answer1') {
        answers.answer1 = event.target.value;
    } else if (event.target.name === 'answer2') {
        answers.answer2 = event.target.value;
    } else if (event.target.name === 'answer3') {
        answers.answer3 = event.target.value;
    }
}
```

From what I know, React should set state by using `setState({answers: {answer1: event.target.value}})`. Am I right? What is the better approach?

Answer (score 3):

Setting/Changing state inside react component always should be using setState, this is what react recommends. The only place where state can directly be modified is the constructor. Read more [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html).

Also worth reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060641/react-changing-the-state-without-using-setstate-must-avoid-it)